# Accessing value of dynamically created controls Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I working in Java Swing and I am generating a dynamic form with control names opc1_1, opc1_2, opc1_3, opc2_1, opc2_2, etc.
How Do I get the value of each one of controls dynamically?
I put a very bad example for illustration

```
for(int i = 1; i < 10; i ++) {
    Control objControl = get("opc1_" + i);
      if(objControl == JComboBox)
        System.out.println(objControl.getSelectedItem().toString());
      else if(objControl == JTextField)
        System.out.println(objControl.getText); 
}
```

Thanks so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array/list to store your `Control` objects, the names of your `Control` objects in your code aren't important.

Then just iterate through your array/list like you would for any other array/list to get the value of each one of your `Control` objects.

Also, `=` is for assignment, `==` is for comparison, and `instanceof` is used for checking if an object is a specific type. You generally try and avoid using the `instanceof` operator in good OO design.

Comment: Yep, or a HashMap if you want to obtain a control by String. 1+

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yeah true. I couldn't see the usefulness of a map for this specific example, it just seems like an unnecessary addition. However, @NestorInc, whenever you need to "map" a string to a specific value/variable, you can use something like a `HashMap`.

Comment: If I needed a bunch of JLabel/JTextField pairs, I've sometimes used an array of Strings for the labels and then created a Map<String, JTextField>, and would create my labels and fields in a for loop, adding to the map and the GUI. Then I could extract text from any field in a public method that accepted as its key the String used by the map and by the JLabel.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yeah in that case it would make more sense to use a `Map`. I've kind of done similar with menus and menu items.

Comment: @AusCBloke your code helped me a lot In my example I put an "=" for quick wrote the code. I used to follow your suggestion intanceOf Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Note that Component has getName() and setName() methods.  As you add more and more components to a container, these are your friend.  I don't think that Container has a method 
getComponentNamed(String s), but it's easy to write.

I second Hovercraft's excellent suggestion of using a Map.